# Add spaces between braces and content

Tags: formatting, balanced-parentheses

I would like to automatically add spaces between braces and content when using emacs, for example:

```
std::vector<std::string> values{"content", "moreContent", "andMoreContent"};
```

becomes

```
std::vector<std::string> values{ "content", "moreContent", "andMoreContent" };
```

when pressing `}`. I'm already using `autopair-mode` which automatically pairs braces and quotes.
Another example, when declaring variables:

```
int myVar{5};
```

becomes

```
int myVar{ 5 };
```

How do I do this?